# How can i change AlertBox into a div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to know how can I change the **AlertBox** into a **div**.

I want the **alertBox** message to appear next to the input but in a div.

Thank You.

This is my Form input code:

```
 <form  name="form" action="gigi.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
 First Name:<br>
 <input  name="name" type="text"  size="30"/><br>
 Last Name:<br />
 <input  name="lname" type="text"  size="30"/><br>
 Email:<br>
 <input  name="caca" type="text"  size="30"/><br>
 Your message:<br>
 <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
 <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send email"/>
 </form>
```

And this is **First Name** input code in JavaScript:

```
  function validateForm(){

 var x=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
      {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;

       }
   }
```

Comment: this is your basic "how do I write this code" question. Those don't get answered much here. Create a div where you want it... instead of using alert, use javascript to dynamically insert contents into that div when you need to. Nothing about that is hard, but it does require you to read a little and understand what you're trying to do. I know that sounds like a lot of work, but I know you have it in you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML add something like:

```
<div id="form-errors"></div>
```

Then in JS, you can do that:

```
var alertDiv = document.getElementById('form-errors');

if (!x || x == '') {
    alertDiv.textContent = 'First name must be filled out!';
}
```

**Readings:**

- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)
- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589007/form-validation-without-alerts)

Comment: this worked thx, i wanted somthing else tho, i wanted the error text to appear in the right side of every input.

Comment: Then add a span tag or something like that right after the field and use its id value to append the error into the proper span.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about forms ? Since HTML5 you can simply write required on the input tab and it won't validate until you write some data.. you can then sanitize it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ramy's response, you can add jquery hide/show effects to display and hide the div element.
Also, do not forget to add style "z-index" to the div, so that it will appear on above other content of web-page.